# Border-Box resizing out of view

Tags: html, css

so lately I came up with this problem: My wrapper has a max-width of 1440px and I want to add a 10px solid border around it. When I add it the border just takes 10px of the max-width and is being displayed, everything's fine. But I want that the border does not take anything of the max-width, I want to display the 10px of the border by 1440px +

One solution would be media queries, I know that, and this also works fine. I am just wondering if there is a solution without adding a seperate wrapper and without media queries so the border just appears, when you resize your window over the 1440px and simply is cut off when you resize the window under 1440px.

Just for anybody who is wondering. I have a boxed layout and want to limit the content area for larger screens, but whish to use full-width on smaller screens.

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly add a position relative to the container and have a z-index set. Then have a pseudo item like :before have position absolute and a negative z-index with the height and width set to match the parent. This will put it behind your content and if you have the border added to it you should be set. Probably will need overflow-x:hidden on the body so it doesn't create a scroll bar. I'll create the code for this soon for reference.

Or a less complex option would be

```
outline:10px solid blue;
```

Outline goes outside of an element even with box-sizing of border-box.

Comment: Hey Nick, thank you very much for your idea. I will try it, but I'd also repreciate your code demo, if you have any time left for this issue in the future :-)

Answer (score 0):

This did it, the next thing I see is how to get a border-radius with the outline. I remember a trick with box-shadow. I will search for it, since the original question wis solved. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Yep box shadow is an option as well. I focused on border and ended up with a more complex solution but there are simpler ways like outline and box shadow